# I got "some of your comments have been reported as spam"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sendmessage

I built an app on facebook, so page owners can use it to make auto-reply on user's comments
When page owner post a post and user start commenting on this post, then the auto-reply start replying them with a comment like "thanks for commenting please call us at 01xxxx"

and i am using facebook graph api to send these replies. On some post i got a lot of comments and then i got this error:
Some of your comments have been reported as spam. To avoid getting blocked again, make sure your posts are in line with the Facebook Community Standards.

I searched a lot on Facebook community but i didn't get certain cause to my case

Could you help me to understand that and if there is any suggestion to overcome this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Replying the very same stuff to all comments on a post? Sounds like a rather un-clever idea to begin with ... If all users commenting need this info, then why not put it into the post itself in the first place? Instead of using features for the sake of using features.

Comment: @CBroe this is kind of marketing strategy to get new contacts from post/ads page post on facebook. To get in touch with them via call/chat and so on

Comment: So, your "marketing strategy" is obviously considered spammy, either by users seeing it, or by Facebook itself ... Solution: Get an _actual_ marketing strategy, instead of posting spam comments.

Comment: There a lot of solution provide this kind of marketing. it is not new idea i created so it is spam. my question here if i had implement any wrong step in this logic. only that

Comment: Neither is "there' other spammers besides me" a valid argument, nor whether or not you came up with the idea yourself.

Comment: ok, you still convinced it is spam :)